# Guass Jordan Elimination Matrix Problem

Tags: matrices

I followed the method as below:

$
   $[A]$  =   \begin{bmatrix}
        8 & 4 & 3 & | & 1 & 0  &0\\
        2 & 1 & 1 & | & 0 & 1  &0 \\
        1 & 2 & 1 & | & 0 & 0  &1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

Interchange $R_1$ and $R_3$

$
       \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 1 & | & 0 & 0  &1\\
       2 & 1 & 1 & | & 0 & 1  &0 \\
        8 & 4 & 3 & | & 1 & 0  &0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

Fix $R_1$ operate $R_2$-$2R_1$ & $R_3$ - $8R_1$

$
       \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 1 & | & 0 & 0  &1\\
       0 & -3 & -1 & | & 0 & 1  &-2 \\
        0 & -12 & -5 & | & 1 & 0  &-8 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

Fix $R_2$ operate $R_3$-$4R_2$

$
       \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 1 & | & 0 & 0  &1\\
       0 & -3 & -1 & | & 0 & 1  &-2 \\
        0 & 0 & -1 & | & 1 & -4  &0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

Fix $R_3$ operate $R_1$+$R_3$ & $R_2 - R_3$

$
       \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 0 & | & 1 & -4  &1\\
       0 & -3 & 0 & | & -1 & 5  &-2 \\
        0 & 0 & -1 & | & 1 & -4  &0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

Fix $C_1$ operate $C_2$-$2C_1$

$
       \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & | & 1 & -6  &1\\
       0 & -3 & 0 & | & -1 & 7  &-2 \\
        0 & 0 & -1 & | & 1 & -6  &0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

Diving $R_2$ by -3 and $R_3$ by -1

$
       \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & | & 1 & -6  &1\\
       0 & 1 & 0 & | & 1/3 & -7/3  & 2/3 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & | & -1 & 6  &0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

When I checked the inverse on a calculator it came up wrong and I cannot seem to figure.

Comment: Row operations means that you multiply the matrix from the left by elementary matrices.
Column operations means from the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it by using only row operations.

Comment: Strange, it worked. So, is it a rule you cannot mix column operations?

Comment: @user12184, yes: you must either use row operations only or column operations only.